# F# compiler error "This expression was expected to have type unit but here has type bool." expression in {if else} statements

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#, unit-type

I have written such a function in F#:

```ml
let TwistBasket (reverse: bool, quarters: int, overTwist: int byref) =
    overTwist <- 50
    WaitForBasketReady()
    waitBasket.Reset()
    let move = 135*quarters - 25 + overTwist
    let speed =
        match reverse with
            | true -> -75y
            | false -> 75y
    let waitHandle = motorBasket.SpeedProfile(speed, 15u, uint32 move, 10u, true)
    Task.Factory.StartNew(fun () ->
        waitHandle.WaitOne()
        if (overTwist <> 0) then
            motorBasket.SpeedProfile(sbyte -speed, 0u, uint32 overTwist, 0u, true).WaitOne()
        waitBasket.Set()
```

On this if statement ;

```ml
    if (overTwist <> 0) then
         motorBasket.SpeedProfile(sbyte -speed, 0u, uint32 overTwist, 0u, true).WaitOne()
```

I get the error: `This expression was expected to have type unit but here has type bool.`

Actually `motorBasket.SpeedProfile().WaitOne()`returns boolean statement. I need it.

Because I'm trying to convert this if else statement in C#:

```cs
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            waitHandle.WaitOne();
            if (overTwist != 0)
            {
                motorBasket.SpeedProfile((sbyte) -speed, 0, (uint) overTwist, 0, true).WaitOne();
            }
            waitBasket.Set();
        });
```

How can I fix my error?

Comment: Have you tried to add |> ignore to the expression?

Comment: If I add |> ignore, still do I call get the results? Because it is very important for me.

Comment: What do you want to do with the result? In the C# version it just ignore it.

Comment: Thank you for your help Gustavo. But actually I'm going to encounter with the similar issues more again, and in the next statements Petr's approach may will be more useful.

Comment: No worries. I would stick to the C# version in principle, then once finished with a working translation I may refactor. Your choice !

Comment: Yes, you're right. I think I have to edit my question later. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By looking at the C# version, it does nothing with the result. So in F# I would call `ignore` which will *eat* the result:

```
if (overTwist <> 0) then
     motorBasket.SpeedProfile(sbyte -speed, 0u, uint32 overTwist, 0u, true).WaitOne() |> ignore
```

F# is more strict than C# in these cases, if your *if .. then* has no *else* branch it result should be unit, which makes perfect sense.

You can also create an else branch with a (dummy) boolean value and let-bind it to a (dummy) value, but in this particular case what's the point if you're really not going to use that value? What you're really doing is creating a side effect and ignoring the result, F# drives you to make it more explicit in your code.

Answer (score 2):

In F# `if/else` expressions should have the same type. If you are using `if` expression without `else` branch then F# compiler consider that implicitly `else` branch has type `unit` hence the error.
You could change your code to explicitly use else branch:

```
if (overTwist <> 0) then
    motorBasket.SpeedProfile(sbyte -speed, 0u, uint32 overTwist, 0u, true).WaitOne()
else
    ... // Put here expression of the same type as if (I assume it's bool)
```

Or you can use `ignore` function in if branch as Gustavo mentioned.

Comment: Actually adding an else branch will not solve the problem alone. You will need to assign the `if .. then .. else .. ` expression to a let-bind value. If that value is not used you can do `let _ = if .. then .. else ..` .. anyway in that case it will better to send the expression to `ignore`, but then you don't need the else ;)