# This expression was expected to have type unit

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, unit-type

I have the following code. in this line

```
 if min<=0  then     min <- List.nth list i |>ignore
```

i have 2 errors.
   first in `0` it is

```
 This expression was expected to have type
    unit    
but here has type
    int
```

and then in `i` it is

```
This expression was expected to have type
    unit    
but here has type
    int
```

*
     I have also seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27735519/f-compiler-error-this-expression-was-expected-to-have-type-unit-but-here-has-t)  and tried ignore, but it doesn't work

```
let replace touple2=
   let first  (a,_,_,_,_)=a
   let second (_,b,_,_,_)=b
   let third  (_,_,c,_,_)=c
   let forth  (_,_,_,d,_)=d
   let fifth  (_,_,_,_,e)=e
   let sortedlist list= List.sort(list)

   let GetMin list=
        list |> List.rev |> List.head
        let mutable min=list.Head
        let mutable i=1
        for i in list do     
            if min<=0  then     min <- List.nth list i |>ignore

        min 

   let GetMax list=list |> List.rev |> List.head

   let A=first  touple2
   let B=second touple2
   let C=third  touple2
   let D=forth  touple2
   let E=fifth  touple2
   let mylist=[A;B;C;D;E]
   let L=sortedlist mylist

   let m1=GetMax L
   printfn "%d"  m1

let touple3= 14,6,18,76,76
replace touple3
```

Comment: Is it supposed to be a puzzle for readers? :)  Try to use parens if you are not sure boundries of the expressions.

Comment: Didn't you already ask this 2 hours ago? http://stackoverflow.com/q/32720710/126014

Answer (score 5):

You do not need the `ignore` - if you are using assignment, it returns `unit` and so you do not have any return value that would have to be ignored:

```
if min <= 0 then min <- List.nth list I
```

That said, this is not very functional approach. So looking into some basic F# book or watching a few talks might help you get started with the langauge in a more F# style.

Answer (score 3):

You just need parentheses to make your intentions clear to the compiler:

```
if min <= 0 then (min <- List.nth list i) |> ignore
```

---

An if without an else in F# is a shorthand for:

```
if condition then doSomething else ()
```

It means the result of whatever is inside the `doSomething` block must be of type `unit`. Since an assignment in F# is an expression, your code was returning `min`, an int value. This explains your first error.

The above happened because, without the parenthesis, the pipe operator was using last parameter os `List.nth`, the `i` as the parameter to `ignore`

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is `list |> List.rev |> List.head` causing the compiler to infer `list`to be of type `unit`. If you delete that line (as it's meaningless anyways, F# lists are immutable, so you are computing an unused value), `list` is correctly inferred to have type `int list` which makes the first error go away (if we also use `List.head list` instead of `list.Head` to make type inference happy).

Then, a second error appears on this line `if min<=0 then min <- List.nth list i |>ignore` which makes sense, as an assignment to a mutable variable should leave nothing to `|> ignore`. So lets get rid of that, fix the deprecation warning and add a bit of formatting... this compiles:

```
let replace touple2 =
   let first  (a,_,_,_,_) = a
   let second (_,b,_,_,_) = b
   let third  (_,_,c,_,_) = c
   let forth  (_,_,_,d,_) = d
   let fifth  (_,_,_,_,e) = e
   let sortedlist list= List.sort(list)

   let GetMin list=
        let mutable min = List.head list
        let mutable i = 1
        for i in list do     
            if min <= 0 then min <- List.item i list

        min 

   let GetMax list = list |> List.rev |> List.head

   let A = first  touple2
   let B = second touple2
   let C = third  touple2
   let D = forth  touple2
   let E = fifth  touple2
   let mylist = [A;B;C;D;E]
   let L = sortedlist mylist

   let m1 = GetMax L
   printfn "%d" m1

let touple3 = 14,6,18,76,76
replace touple3
```

Still, it doesn't really look F#-ish. How about this (including wild guesses what you want to achieve):

```
let printMinMax (a, b, c, d, e) =

    let minPositive sortedList = 
        sortedList |> List.fold (fun m e -> if m <= 0 then e else m) sortedList.Head

    let max sortedList = sortedList |> List.last

    let sortedList = [ a; b; c; d; e ] |> List.sort

    printfn "min %d, max %d" (minPositive sortedList) (max sortedList)

let t1 = 14, 6, 18, 76, 76
printMinMax t1

let t2 = -1, -5, 5, 16, 12
printMinMax t2
```

This could be improved further, but I fear the connection to the original becomes even less obvious (and it expects at least one positive value to be present):

```
let minMax (a, b, c, d, e) =
    let l = [ a; b; c; d; e ] |> List.sortDescending
    let positiveMin = l |> List.findBack ((<) 0)
    let max = l.Head
    positiveMin, max

let t1 = 14, 6, 18, 76, 76
let t2 = -1, -5, 5, 16, 12

let test t =
    let min, max = minMax t
    printfn "min (positive) %d, max %d" min max

test t1
test t2
```